# multisite - unable to connect to network administration

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I install wordpress and set my website as multisite to have many sites

I certainly make a mistake as I can't access to network administration anymore
so I can't add a new site or see themes ....

I don't know where to search and any help will be welcome

Comment: If you haven't made much content, starting over might be easiest, or reverting to a backup. Failing that, there's not enough information here to really help

Comment: I already make 3 sites. That is why I would prefer to find a solution. I can give any informations but don't know what can help?

Comment: You may get more answers if you describe the steps you have taken so far to resolve your issue and any steps that may have contributed to the problem.